# boost::optional vs std::optional for non copyable objects

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, language-lawyer

I tried to update from VS2015 to VS2017 and the code below does not work in the newer version. As you can see a move constructor is defined which automatically deletes the copy constructor.

```
#include <boost/optional.hpp>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(Foo&& other) {}
};

int main() {
    std::vector<boost::optional<Foo>> foos;
    foos.resize(42);
    return 0;
}
```

The compilation error is

```
1>...\boost\dist\include\boost-1_66\boost\optional\optional.hpp(384): error C2280: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
1>...\main.cpp(7): note: compiler has generated 'Foo::Foo' here
1>...\boost\dist\include\boost-1_66\boost\optional\optional.hpp(383): note: while compiling class template member function 'void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::construct(const Foo &)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Foo
1>        ]
1>...\boost\dist\include\boost-1_66\boost\optional\optional.hpp(181): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>::construct(const Foo &)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Foo
1>        ]
1>...\boost\dist\include\boost-1_66\boost\optional\optional.hpp(831): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional_detail::optional_base<T>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            T=Foo
1>        ]
1>...\msvc\14.12.25827\include\vector(1902): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::optional<Foo>' being compiled
1>...\msvc\14.12.25827\include\vector(1901): note: while compiling class template member function 'boost::optional<Foo> *std::vector<boost::optional<Foo>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Udefault(boost::optional<Foo> *,const unsigned __int64)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::optional<Foo>
1>        ]
1>...\msvc\14.12.25827\include\vector(1528): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::optional<Foo> *std::vector<boost::optional<Foo>,std::allocator<_Ty>>::_Udefault(boost::optional<Foo> *,const unsigned __int64)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::optional<Foo>
1>        ]
1>...\main.cpp(10): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::vector<boost::optional<Foo>,std::allocator<_Ty>>' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Ty=boost::optional<Foo>
1>        ]
1>...\main.cpp(7): note: 'Foo::Foo(const Foo &)': function was implicitly deleted because 'Foo' has a user-defined move constructor
```

Now the interesting thing is that it does compile when I use `std::optional` instead of `boost::optional`. I am not really sure what the issue is and who to blame: me, boost, microsoft, the c++ standard? Anyone knows what is going on?

Is this a known issue? Is it a bug in boost or is it correct that it does not work?

Comment: They're different libraries, sure, one was largely based on the other, but why would you expect them to be identical?  That's partly why they're in different namespaces.

Comment: why do you want to use boost if you can use `std::optional`?

Comment: This has to be a bug. According to [boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/optional/doc/html/boost_optional/tutorial/type_requirements.html) a move-constructible type can be used to make a move-constructible `optional`. This overload of `vector::resize` does not call a copy constructor, so I don't see why VS is attempting to compile it. It might be a bug with templated code.

Comment: @patatahooligan gcc and clang also do not compile. If it's a bug then not of MSVC

Comment: @patatahooligan I thought the move constructor had to be noexcept to give the strong exception guarantee.  If it is not then resize will try and use the copy constructor (which does not need to be noexcept) to give the same strong exception guarantee (the original collection will be unchanged if an exception is thrown by move/copy of the contained objects) .

Comment: @RichardCritten Changed the `Foo`'s move constructor to `noexcept` and it compiled. However, I though both `std::optional` and `boost::optional` did not declare constructors and the language declares them implicitly based on their contained types. So why is the result different?

Comment: Suggest we add [language-lawyer] to this question as I don't have the necessary knowledge.

Comment: Looking at the source code, it appears that both implementations define templated move-constructors, so disregard my previous comment about them being implicitly declared.

Comment: @UKMonkey I know they are different libraries but usually boost tries really hard to keep the semantics kind of the same

Comment: @RichardCritten That's interesting. I can reproduce that behavior here. But I would also be interested in an argumentation with a reference to the c++ standard

Comment: @Daniel can you accept the tag change or do we have to wait for a review (not quite sure how edits work)?

Comment: @RichardCritten Never did it before - Accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an issue with the STL implementations.

From the latest draft, n4700:

**26.2.1 General container requirements** [container.requirements.general] defines `DefaultInsertable` and `MoveInsertable`, and also states in part:

> `T` is *`CopyInsertable`* into `X` means that, in addition to `T` being `MoveInsertable` into `X`, the following expression is well-formed:
>
> ```
> allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p, v)
> ```
>
> and its evaluation causes the following postcondition to hold: The value of `v` is unchanged and is equivalent to `*p`.

(In this case, `T` is `boost::optional<Foo>`, `X` is `std::vector<T>`.)

Clearly, `T` is `DefaultInsertable` and `MoveInsertable` but not `CopyInsertable`.

**26.3.11.3 `vector` capacity** [vector.capacity] states in part:

> ```
> void resize(size_type sz);
> ```
>
> *Effects:* If `sz < size()`, erases the last `size() - sz` elements from the sequence. Otherwise, appends `sz - size()` default-inserted elements to the sequence.
>
> *Requires:* `T` shall be `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable` into `*this`.
>
> *Remarks:* If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` `T` there are no effects.

Although I do not possess official copies of C++11 or C++14, based on working copies, C++11 did not have the "*Remarks:*" paragraph and had a slightly different "*Requires:*" paragraph:

> *Requires:* `T` shall be `CopyInsertable` into `*this`.

Therefore, `foos.resize(42)` is not well-formed in C++11, but it should be well-formed in C++14 because the requirements that `T` be `MoveInsertable` and `DefaultInsertable` into the vector are satisfied.

I have confirmed [@patatahooligan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48340618/boostoptional-vs-stdoptional-for-non-copyable-objects#comment83667949_48340618) that adding `noexcept` to the `Foo` move constructor allows the code to compile in Clang and g++ 7.2.0. However, unless I am misreading the standard, it is not a requirement that a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`'s move constructor be noexcept; in fact, the standard seems to allow for the possibility that a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`'s move constructor can throw an exception, in which case it's not guaranteed whether there were effects.

**UPDATE** I have filed GCC Bugs [83981](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83981) and [83982](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83982).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For my use case it does not really matter because my move constructor can be noexcept anyway. But did I understand you correctly that this seems to be an issue with the implementation in VS, clang AND GCC? Isn't this really unlikely?

Comment: @Daniel On your last two questions, my answers are yes, and maybe. Because of the change in behavior between C++11 and C++14, it might be the STL implementations were not updated. I found [GCC Bug 64147](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64147) which is very similar to your question; however, that bug report is invalid because the `Foo` type there is not `MoveInsertable`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and also the bug report!